# Send result as string instead of array with Selectize.js multiselect

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I am using `<select>` for multiple select option, it works great but I need it to send the data (after post) as string (comma delimiter) and not array. That is because I have some dynamic fields, which user can add (click to add row, which appends the entire row and its element) and with array, its difficult separate the options, as they are matched with amount.

So for example, currently its like this:

```
    [name]=> blah
    [options] => Array(
                  [0] => 1
                  [1] => 2
                  [2] => 3
                  [3] => 4
                  )
    [amount] => Array(
                  [0] => 100
                  [1] => 200
                    )
    [Save] => Save
```

Whereas I need it to be like this:

```
    [name]=> blah
    [options] => Array(
                  [0] => 1,2
                  [1] => 3,4
                  )
    [amount] => Array(
                  [0] => 100
                  [1] => 200
                  )
    [Save] => Save
```

From what I can gather the problem is with using `<select>`, if I use `<input>` which works fine, but given the options are in `value` the field is already preloaded, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best fix, but I have got it working the way I was hoping, albeit with  array, array [][]. I changed the name of the fields to `options[][]` and `amount[][]`. So now I get the following:

```
    [options] => Array(
      [0] => Array(
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
    )

    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 7
        [3] => 8
        [4] => 9
        )
     )

    [amount] => Array(
      [0] => Array(
        [0] => 100
    )

    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 200
       )
    )
```

**Thank you so much!**